# Why "man CMD" shows nothing?

Tags: man

After I ran `man ls`, it shows:

> Man: find all matching manual pages
>   * ls (1)
>   ls (1p)
>   Man: What manual page do you want?
>   Man:

After I entered "1", it shows nothing but "*Manual page ls(1) line ?/? (END)*" on the status bar.

I guess that I haven't installed manual page for `ls`, so I ran `manpath` and get output  below:

> /usr/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man

Right under directory `/usr/share/man/man1/` I found gzip file `ls.1.gz`, which I think is the manual information of `ls`.

So why `man ls` shows nothing here?

Comment: What system are you using?  Try `man 1 ls` or `man -s 1 ls`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: These two commands failed too. I'm using SLES 11.

Comment: Failed how exactly?  `zcat /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz | head` should show you 10 lines of text; one of the lines should be something similar to `.TH LS "1" "February 2011" "GNU coreutils 8.5" "User Commands"`.  And try `zcat /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz | nroff -man | less`.

Comment: Also try `man 1p ls` (that's digit 1 letter p).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Thanks for your detailed reply. (1) `man 1 ls`, `man -s 1 ls` and `man 1p ls` show nothing ---- blank page with only "Manual page ls(1p) line ?/? (END)" on the status bar. (2) `zcat /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz | head` acts just like you said. (3) `zcat /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz | nroff -man | less` shows a lot, which looks like normal "man ls" output, but is kind of ill-formed. For example "ESC[1mNAMEESC[0m
       ls - list directory contents" and "ESC[1mSYNOPSISESC[0m
       ESC[1mls ESC[22m[ESC[4mOPTIONESC[24m]... [ESC[4mFILEESC[24m]..."

Comment: you can try to display your ls manual with this command : `man -l /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz`. Is this working for you ?

Comment: @Coren: No, nothing showed, and on status bar displayed "Manual page ls.1.gz line ?/? (END)"

Comment: Do you have `man` aliased? What do `alias man` and `which man` tell you?

Comment: Try these: `type -a man`, `/usr/bin/man ls`

Comment: @Mat: Thanks. `alias man` outputs "-bash: alias: man: not found" and `which man` outputs "/usr/bin/man", which means that `man` program is correct. I solved the problem, please see my edit for details.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Thanks. `type -a man` shows that `man` program is the correct one and `/usr/bin/man ls` shows nothing as before. But I solved the problem in another way, I edit the question. :)

Comment: You should post the answer as an answer, not edit it into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks all for your suggestions.

I finally solved the problem and now `man` works.

#### Answer

Somebody installed both 64bit and 32bit version of `glibc`, which brings chaos I guess. After uninstall the 32bit version and reinstall 64bit version of `glibc`, `man` works.

== Detailed process ==

- Ran `mandb -t`, lots of error messages showed up:

> iconv_open ("UTF-8//IGNORE", "ISO-8859-1"): Invalid argument

- By google I found that `iconv_open` is in `gconv`[(ref)](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/glibc-iconv-Implementation.html).
- `strace mandb -t` and `strace man ls` both show this information:

> open("/usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> open("/usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

- By google I found that gconv-modules may be very important to `iconv`, which might be very important to `man`. And gconv is in `glibc`, now the best guess is that my `glibc` is not installed correctly.
- Ran `rpm -qa | grep glibc`, I got this:

> glibc-i18ndata-2.11.1-0.17.4
> glibc-locale-2.11.1-0.17.4
> glibc-info-2.11.1-0.17.4
> glibc-html-2.11.1-0.17.4
> glibc-profile-2.11.1-0.17.4
> glibc-devel-2.11.1-0.17.4
> glibc-2.11.1-0.17.4
> glibc-32bit-2.11.1-0.17.4
> glibc-devel-32bit-2.11.1-0.17.4
> glibc-locale-32bit-2.11.1-0.17.4
> glibc-profile-32bit-2.11.1-0.17.4

- Ran `rpm -e --nodeps 32bit-PACKAGE` to remove all the 32bit packages, then reboot the machine(Any other way beside reboot?).
- Reinstalled all the 64bit glibc packages.
- `man ls`, it worked!

Answer (score -2):

Finally the **correct** answer to this error as well:

```
QIconvCodec::convertToUnicode: using Latin-1 for conversion, iconv_open failed
QIconvCodec::convertFromUnicode: using Latin-1 for conversion, iconv_open failed
```

It does **not** have anything to do with your installed fonts, but with missing glibc-packages.